# Why do I get the same FPS with "optirun glxspheres64" in comparison with just "glxspheres64"?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, performance, bumblebee

```
$ vblank_mode=0 optirun ./glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2
218.417930 frames/sec - 243.754410 Mpixels/sec
222.284833 frames/sec - 248.069873 Mpixels/sec
220.976371 frames/sec - 246.609630 Mpixels/sec
213.462514 frames/sec - 238.224166 Mpixels/sec
217.160795 frames/sec - 242.351447 Mpixels/sec
219.719268 frames/sec - 245.206703 Mpixels/sec
```

---

```
$ vblank_mode=0 ./glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
244.416640 frames/sec - 272.768970 Mpixels/sec
214.628904 frames/sec - 239.525857 Mpixels/sec
215.807053 frames/sec - 240.840672 Mpixels/sec
212.618440 frames/sec - 237.282179 Mpixels/sec
215.407467 frames/sec - 240.394733 Mpixels/sec
217.956713 frames/sec - 243.239692 Mpixels/sec
215.350718 frames/sec - 240.331402 Mpixels/sec
```

Isn't there a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it dude!

Just delete Bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
```

And then just say "hello!" to Nvidia-Prime

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

After selecting your graphic card from nvidia-settings, (intel or nvidia)

you should log out and come back. (Unfortunately after every changes)

new glxspheres64 outs;

`./glxspheres64`

```
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
Visual ID of window: 0x62
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2
1278.419990 frames/sec - 1426.716709 Mpixels/sec
1313.904494 frames/sec - 1466.317416 Mpixels/sec
1319.530930 frames/sec - 1472.596518 Mpixels/sec
1315.465344 frames/sec - 1468.059324 Mpixels/sec
1319.271645 frames/sec - 1472.307156 Mpixels/sec
```

Finally good results :)